# OpenVINO unable to get optimum performance while running multiple inference engines

Tags: python-multithreading, openvino

I am running multiple python processes( 4 in this case using multiprocessing module) for person detection (using ssd mobilenet model), each having it's own inference engine of OpenVINO. I am getting a very low FPS (not more than 10) for each process.  My suspicion is the CPUs are not getting utilized optimally because the number of threads being spawned by each engine are high, which is adding to the overhead and also the sharing of CPUs across processes.
Also for single process, I am getting upto 60fps with OMP_NUM_THREADS set to 4.

```
My CPU details are:-
2 Sockets 
4 cores each socket 
1 thread each core 
Total - 8 CPUs
```

So what would be the

1. Optimal value for OMP_NUM_THREADS in this case?
2. How can I avoid Sharing of CPUs across each process?

Currently I am playing with OMP_NUM_THREADS and KMP_AFFINITY variables, but just doing a hit and trail on setting the values. Any detail on how to set would be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case of multiple networks inference you may try to set `OMP_WAIT_POLICY` to `PASSIVE`.

BTW, OpenVINO 2019R1 moved from OpenMP to TBB. It might give better efficiency in case of deep learning networks pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using the same model for all the processes consider to use OV multi-stream inference. Using this you can load single network and next to create a multiple infer requests. Using this you will have a better CPU utilization (if compare to running one infer request across multiple cores) and in result better throughput.

To understand how to use multi stream inference take a look on inference_engine/samples/python_samples/benchmark_app/benchmark sample

As well you can use benchmark sample to do a grid search to find an optimal configuration (number of streams, batch size).